# Is it possible to self-reference and switch boolean during an update phase?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this update function to switch a boolean status every time it is executed, but seemingly it doesn't work as expected.

```
Message.update({}, { $set: { favorite: !this.favorite } }, { multi: true }, function(err, docs) {
});
```

If all messages are not marked as favorite, so in the first time it is executed switch all messages to true, in the second time this suppose to be false again, but it not happens, why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Self reference? No. But you were given a very good answer for exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Since [Mongo 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/) you can use the new bitwise update operator. See [Mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/) for more details:

This would require you to change the field `favorite` from boolean to integer.

To toggle the value use this update statement:

```
db.message.update(
  { }, 
  { $bit: { favorite: { xor: NumberInt(1) } } }
)
```

On each execution the value of `favorite` will toggle (1 to 0, 0 to 1).

Comment: This would be a nice answer if you actually just explained it a little more

Comment: @NeilLunn: Added some more explanation. Hopefully more useful now.

Comment: It is not quite I have been expected for, cause' you have to change your data type.

Comment: @Ito But this is the only way in Mongo to accomplish your requirement